# R- accessing list of list from a dataframe

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame (below) generated from
`{ a<-as.data.frame(entrez_db_searchable(db = "pubmed", config = NULL)) }`

```
  Name          FullName        
1  ALL          All Fields        
2  UID          UID        
3 FILT          Filter        
4 TITL          Title        
5 WORD          Text Word        
6 MESH          MESH Terms
```

---

MeSH Terms

I would like to access all the elements in `a$FullName`. The result looks like list of list.

```
$ALL 
[1] "All Fields"
$UID
 [1] "UID"
 $FILT
 [1] "Filter"
```

and so on...

I am trying to and was unsuccessful to access the expanded terms in the list in the following format
`a <- some_simple_function(df$FullName)`
print (a)
output of the expanded terms stored in 1x1 column ( each row for each term).

```
Full Name
1  All Fields
2  UID
3  Filter
4  Title
5  MeSH Terms
```

and so on.....

I appreciate if anyone can help me out. 
Note: I tried the following 
1) for loop. ( prefer to see if there is a better way than for loop)
2) `do.call("paste", c(a$FullName, sep = "\n"))`paste does not recognize new line "\n" argument.
3) `cat(do.call("paste", c(a$FullName, sep = "\n")))` , prints out the exact output I am looking for, but it is a print statement. I need to store the output in another variable.

Comment: Is `unlist(a$FullName, use.names = FALSE)` what you want?

Comment: This also worked for me : `data.frame(Names = names(a$FullName))`

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you. it worked for me.

Comment: Hi AntoniosK, That is exact output what I am looking for, serverd for purpose 1. Thank you. Richard scriven, your suggestion actually helped me implement other task.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite able to get your example data frame working, but this worked for me:

```
library(rentrez)
a<-as.data.frame(entrez_db_searchable(db = "pmc", config = NULL))
```

To deal with the fact that `a$FullName` is returning a list of 1-element vectors, you can use `unlist` to grab a vector of the names:

```
data.frame(FullName=unlist(a[,"FullName"]))
#                         FullName
# ALL                   All Fields
# UID                          UID
# FILT                      Filter
# PMID                   PubMed ID
# AUTH                      Author
# ...
```

Comment: Hi Josilber, unlist actually helped me . Thank you for suggestions guys. I used it in my attempts, but used it in the wrong way. Need to go back and read document. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/flatten.html

`flatten()` is a tidy way of doing `unlist()`

This should work:

```
a %>%
  transmute(
  FullName = flatten_chr(FullName)
  )
```